# Vim Solarized setting Mac terminal not working as expected

Tags: macos, vim, macvim, color-scheme

## Problem

From the solarized site, it appears that solarized-dark looks like this:
[image]

Mine looks like this, with the ~/.vimrc for extra helpfulness. (Same background but slightly different colors for some reason)

[image]

## Attempts To Fix

It appears that my color scheme is just too high of contrast. I'm not sure what exactly is going on, and if you can see from my ~/.vimrc, I've tried a couple things:

```
if !has('gui_running')
    "Compatibility for Terminal
    let g:solarized_termtrans=1

    " Make Solarized use 16 colors for Terminal support
    let g:solarized_termcolors=16
endif

syntax enable
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
```

This is my preference screen from the Mac settings screen:
[image]

#### Some more specs

- I'm using normal terminal vim, v7.4.0 on Mac OSX El Capitan.
- When I change the settings in terminal preferences to "Basic", the vim colors are even stranger(and I effectively cannot get it to display dark, it displays a strange light version of solarized).
- If necessary, I will post a picture of that as well.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand, you say you are using "macvim, normal terminal" but MacVim is the GUI, the terminal is just Vim. Which one you're using? To me it seems that the standard terminal is not reproducing all the colors, if the theme is intended to be used in a GUI

Comment: @sidyll Hi, I overrode the system vim as the default terminal vim editor. I installed it using homebrew with the flag --with-override-system-vim I believe. I know that system vim is in /usr/bin/vim, and when I did "which vim", it was actually in /usr/local/bin/vim, which means it was downloaded from homebrew. I also just did "vim -version" and it said 7.4, while the system vim, I believe was 7.0.x last time I checked. That's how I know it was macvim in the terminal. I'm not sure if that's the correct terminology, however. My bad for any confusions!

Comment: MacVim is the GUI. If you're using on the terminal, you're using just Vim. Doesn't matter if system or your own installation, it is Vim —not MacVim. So I was reading the solarized github page and they have instructions there. What is probably happening is that you are setting it to use 16 colors but the terminal palette is different from what it should be. Terminals generally have much less colors than these themes require. So the solution might be to modify the terminal palette, as described in their page

Comment: @sidyll Ah okay, thank you! I see the section where it says to "If you are going to use Solarized in Terminal mode, please please please consider setting your terminal emulator's colorscheme to used the Solarized palette. I've included palettes for some popular terminal emulator as well as Xdefaults in the official Solarized download available from Solarized homepage." However, it appears that I did set the colorscheme to Solarized palette. I thought because of that, the color scheme would be set automatically after I choose the color palette. Perhaps not.

Comment: I understand. Please access the terminal preferences again and check those color values for the solarized palette. Just to eliminate this, if they are correct indeed. Might be helpful to declare the terminal as xterm-16 (in the same tab which you shown in your screenshot here) or try the 256 approach within Vim settings for this theme and terminal as well

Comment: @sidyll Thank you. I tried to do the following so far:

1. Changed the terminal as xterm-16

2. Added the 256 color command within my ~/.vimrc

3. I checked the colors inside of the text tab and it seems that the colors are not what solaris had in their documentations. I don't see a way to change them to the hex representations that solaris's website suggested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108007/discussion-between-oneraynyday-and-sidyll).